# Python casting leads to weird mutability result

Tags: python, list, mutability

Why is it that when I write the code block as:

```
def rev(li):
    li.reverse()

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

map(rev, l)

print(l)
```

The resulting list is the same as the original list, but when I rewrite the code to now cast the map object into a list as such:

```
def rev(li):
    li.reverse()

l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

list(map(rev, l))

print(l)
```

It does reverse the inner lists to give me [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]].  How does casting the map object to a list change mutability rules for the list `l`?

Comment: Just a pet peeve of mine, although "casting" is often used to men "type conversion" it really isn't a concept that belongs in Python. A better way to think about it in Python is that `list(x)` creates a list by using the list constructor on an iterable.

Comment: Anyway, doing `list(map(...))` *consumes the `map` iterator*. That means the function runs on every element of the list. Before that, the function hasn't been called at all. This isn't weird at all, what did you *expect* to happen?

Comment: I just want to emphasize that answer, in case the point was missed.  The statement `map(rev, l)` does nothing.  It sets up an iterator that is read to go, but the `rev` function will not be called until you try to read from the `map`.

Comment: "How does casting the map object to a list change mutability rules for the list `l`?" What *exactly* do you mean? What is the mutability rules for the list that you are referring to? List objects are mutable. Your `rev` function mutates the list that is passed as the argument.  You should *expect* this function to mutate the lists.